# Show/Hide part of InfoPath form based on the chosen option from the drop-down list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath, form

So I am trying to select an option from drop down list so that it should only show the info path form related to that particular section

Answer (score 0):

in InfoPath form, we have concept for `formatting rules`, which is used these task. You can add `formatting rules` to show/hide form components.

There is a very good documentation by MS on same. Follow the URL to learn more. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-formatting-rules-C9171387-0061-43CC-9D54-E260A6B8F9A9

Comment: can we do this with creating multiple views with in the same form and load while selecting the option in drop down?????

Comment: I didnt use InfoPath much, but I guess, as long as you are using InfoPath Section Container you can achieve what you desire.

Comment: You can vote up or mark answer if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: Nope it did solved my answer to half

Comment: Where it stuck?